# Issue with ONNX Runtime dynamic axes for output shape

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, onnx, onnxruntime

I'm working on a small project in which I trained a Neural Network for binary image classification. I got the training done and now I just want to create a GUI for it. Since I'm working with PyTorch and I don't want to install it as all I need is to use the mode, I decided to use the `onnx` and `onnxruntime` packages to just load the model saved in an .onnx file.

Evertything works fine if I try to predict the label for just 1 image. The problem arises when I try to make a prediction for a batch of images (more than 1 image) because for some reason ONNX is complaining that the output shape is not the one expected, even though I specified that the output's first axis (the batch size) should be dynamic. *See the error below*.

```py
[W:onnxruntime:, execution_frame.cc:835 onnxruntime::ExecutionFrame::VerifyOutputSizes] 
Expected shape from model of {} does not match actual shape of {2} for output output
```

This is the code I used to export the model from PyTorch into a .onnx file:

```py
loaded_model.eval()
torch.onnx.export(loaded_model, 
                  dummy_img, 
                  "trained_model_3.onnx",
                  export_params=True,
                  do_constant_folding=True,
                  verbose=False,
                  dynamic_axes={'input' : {0 : 'batch_size'},    # variable length axes
                                'output' : {0 : 'batch_size'}},
                  input_names=input_names,
                  output_names=output_names)
```

And just for the sake of showing the input shape and output shape of the Neural Network:

```py
class Model(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.conv1_block = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=(3, 3)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2)
        )

        # ... other layers ...
                
        self.output = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(10, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )
        
    def forward(self, x : torch.Tensor):
        x = self.conv1_block(x)

        # ... other layers ...

        return self.output(x).squeeze()
```

So the input has a size of `(3, 255, 255)` (color channels, width, height) and the output is just one number in the range 0 to 1 (inclusive)

This is the code I use for loading an image:

```py
def loadImageToArray(self, imgPath: str) -> np.ndarray:
    img = Image.open(imgPath)
    img = img.resize((255, 255))
    
    imgArr = np.asarray(img, dtype=np.float32)
    imgArr = imgArr.transpose((2, 0, 1)) / 255

    return imgArr
```

`imgArr` will have a shape of `(3, 255, 255)`, obviously this is missing the batch_size dimension. Later I implement a for loop that just reads and loads all valid images in a directory and append them all to a numpy array. That numpy array will have a shape of (# of loaded images, 3, 255, 255). I tried testing the code that does this with just 2 images, the resulting shape of the numpy array is `(2, 3, 255, 255)`, then I ran this code:

```py
def predict(self, dirPath: str):
    imgArr = self.loadImgsInDir(dirPath)   # This is the function that loads all images in a dir
                                           # and returns a np.ndarray with all of the images.
    input = {self.__modelSession.get_inputs()[0].name: imgArr}
    res = self.__modelSession.run(None, input)
```

I expected to get a new array containing 2 elements, the model's prediction of the label of each image but I got the error I specified at the start of this question.
I don't know why ONNXRuntime is complaining since I specified that input and output should be dynamic axes, and oddly I don't get any error for the input of the model, just for the output.